# is SSL version 2 still in use?

Tags: ssl

As the title, is SSL version 2 still in use? Or now is used only SSLv3? What is the spread of SSLv3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSLv2 is still enabled by default on most web server software (Apache, IIS), but should be disabled when security is a concern.

Any modern browser will connect over SSLv3 or TLS when available, but for the most part maintain the ability to fall back to SSLv2 if the server they're connecting to doesn't support a newer protocol.

So, the concise version: it's on its way out, and you're probably safe disabling it unless you have to support really ancient browsers, but it's not yet gone.

Comment: For what it's worth, we disable SSLv2 on all our webservers as a standard practice, and we've never heard any complaints.